# cross compiling why cant ld find shared library / how to debug further?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

Im trying to cross-compile and link aggregate on ubuntu for my arm-router and I get the following error.  In the past I think I have been able to workaround this by setting the appropriate environment variable but this time is not working .  Can anyone help me figure out why this might not work:

`/home/ubuntu/Downloads/toolchain-arm_cortex-a9_gcc-4.9-linaro_musl-1.1.2_eabi/bin/../lib64/gcc/arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi/4.9.1/../../../../arm-openwrt-linux-muslgnueabi/bin/ld:`

`cannot find -lpopt`

however libpopt.so exists in :
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Sep 10 12:46 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0`

I set the following environment variables , in order of desperation, to no avail.

`LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/include/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Thinking that it might be caused because it might be a target architecture issue (ie maybe i need libpopt.so built for the target of the cross-compile) I copied the libpopt.so from the router to my ubuntu and set the paths again.  Again to no avail.

What might I be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to specify the path to the lib using -L in the Makefile as follows:
-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

additionally I *did* have to use the target arhchitecture version of libpopt.so which i copied into a new dir and used that in the argument to -L/home/Downloads/lib/.  For whatever reason LIBRARY_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH were not being picked up.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used at runtime of executables, not for specifying where to look for libraries when linking.

Answer (score 4):

Please, please don't be copying ARM binaries into /lib/**x86_64**-linux-gnu. This is a great way to mess up your Linux installation.

Instead, make a directory for cross-compilation dependencies, put the foreign libraries there, and put that directory on your linker search path with the `-L` option.

Comment: yeah i didnt actually do that, though through editting i made it sound like i did .  I updated my previous post.  Thanks