# Bluetooth Linux ARM file transfer

Tags: linux, bluetooth, arm, cross-compiling, file-transfer

I have a control board with BCM434 chip on it. Trying to get Bluetooth running for few days. I am pretty new to this, and checking question in related topics helps, but not quite that beginner friendly.

**what I need my device do**:
I need to make my device a server for other device to connect through Bluetooth and send files to my device. my board doesn't have a way to input, so connection without pin input or auto input will be best.

**Here is what i find so far**:
I followed the guide on this link: https://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_BlueZ_Bluetooth_tools_for_ARM to install bluez (version 5.28 though with required libs downloading from this link:http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/7.7/general/bluez.html). It helps a lot on understanding how bluez required, but unfortunately, I run into trouble on Building BlueZ "make" part. with following error:

```
make --no-print-directory all-am
CCLD   client/bluetoothctl
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -ldbus-1
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lreadline
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [client/bluetoothctl] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I read through chapter 4 of following link:https://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/c404.html

so I assume if I install bluez correctly, I can just write a bash script that runs bluez or 'hciconfig hci0 up' to wake the bluetooth. Then I just run the script on system start?

I really need a clear guide on the things I need to make it work and what part did I misunderstood. Right now I'm in the mode of read a guide from ~2014, download files, compile them and found errors in one of them (repeat).

Thank you for speeding time reading through this question, appreciate your help in any sort.

Comment: sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libdbus-1-dev libreadline-dev

Comment: just did that, but the error still shows same

Comment: Strange. Let's focus on a single library (let's say `readline`). `find /usr -name "libreadline.so*"` (you want dynamic linking, right?). If you have it, check your ld configuration, maybe the default library path is not configured correctly.

Comment: you are correct the path is under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so i guess it will be same for others, what do i configure to change ld configuration?

Comment: You are using ARM compiler, but the library is installed in x86_64, most probably this is a problem. How to solve it depends on your environment, it's difficult to tell anything else without the access to your board and code. Read some topics about cross compiling like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773759/cross-compiling-why-cant-ld-find-shared-library-how-to-debug-further).

Comment: thank you a lot, I will look more into it.